# Sonar-CSharp doesn't analyze .cs files

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm running the sonar qube runner with teamcity. It completes the step without any errors but it doesn't find any issues.

The project structure like:

root
-sources
--projectA
---projectA.csproj
--projectB
---projectB.csproj
-tests
--projectAtests
---projectAtests.csproj
--projectBtests
---projectBtests.csproj
-solution.sln

The configured parameters are:
working directory:

source location: "sources"

tests location: "tests"

Additional parameters: "-Dsonar.resharper.cs.reportPath=%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%\inspectReport.xml
-Dsonar.resharper.solutionFile=%solutionproject%
-X"

The log looks looks like this:

```
    Starting SQS from C:\BuildAgent\tools\sonar-qube-scanner.3.0.3.778-scanner
-classpath
C:\BuildAgent\tools\sonar-qube-scanner.3.0.3.778-scanner\lib\sonar-scanner-cli-3.0.3.778.jar
org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main
"-Dproject.home=."
"-Dsonar.host.url=http://teamcity:9000"
"-Dsonar.projectKey=MyProj"
"-Dsonar.projectName=MyProj"
"-Dsonar.projectVersion=84"
"-Dsonar.sources=Sources"
"-Dsonar.tests=Tests"
"-Dsonar.password=*******"
"-Dsonar.login=*******"
-Dscanner.home=C:\BuildAgent\tools\sonar-qube-scanner.3.0.3.778-scanner
-Dsonar.resharper.cs.reportPath=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\inspectReport.xml
-Dsonar.resharper.solutionFile=MyProj
-X
Starting: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" -classpath C:\BuildAgent\tools\sonar-qube-scanner.3.0.3.778-scanner\lib\sonar-scanner-cli-3.0.3.778.jar org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main "-Dproject.home=." "-Dsonar.host.url=http://teamcity:9000" "-Dsonar.projectKey=MyProj" "-Dsonar.projectName=MyProj" "-Dsonar.projectVersion=84" "-Dsonar.sources=Sources" "-Dsonar.tests=Tests" "-Dsonar.password=*******" "-Dsonar.login=*******" -Dscanner.home=C:\BuildAgent\tools\sonar-qube-scanner.3.0.3.778-scanner -Dsonar.resharper.cs.reportPath=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\inspectReport.xml -Dsonar.resharper.solutionFile=MyProj -X
in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\a5fc21edc9db6866
14:05:27.272 INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\BuildAgent\tools\sonar-qube-scanner.3.0.3.778-scanner\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
14:05:27.279 INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
14:05:27.307 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
14:05:27.307 INFO: Java 1.8.0_144 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
14:05:27.307 INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
14:05:27.581 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
14:05:27.581 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
14:05:27.581 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
14:05:27.581 DEBUG: init keystore
14:05:27.582 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
14:05:27.799 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\support\.sonar\cache
14:05:27.800 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
14:05:27.876 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
14:05:27.877 DEBUG: Download: http://teamcity:9000/batch/index
14:05:27.951 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
14:05:27.953 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
14:05:27.967 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
14:05:27.978 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
14:05:27.978 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
14:05:27.984 DEBUG: Execution start
14:05:28.276 INFO: Publish mode
14:05:28.431 INFO: Load global settings
14:05:28.515 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=54ms
14:05:28.537 INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=106ms
14:05:28.547 INFO: Server id: AWANnH2mQgX7CJzKVokm
14:05:28.557 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\support\.sonar\cache
14:05:28.823 INFO: Load plugins index
14:05:28.835 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/plugins/installed | time=12ms
14:05:28.877 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=54ms
14:05:28.878 DEBUG: Load plugins
14:05:28.899 DEBUG: Load plugins (done) | time=21ms
14:05:28.921 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin Git [scmgit] (built with API lower than 5.2)
14:05:28.926 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin SVN [scmsvn] (built with API lower than 5.2)
14:05:29.070 DEBUG: Plugins:
14:05:29.070 DEBUG:   * SonarC# 6.7.0.4267 (csharp)
14:05:29.070 DEBUG:   * SonarPython 1.8.0.1496 (python)
14:05:29.071 DEBUG:   * SonarJava 4.15.0.12310 (java)
14:05:29.072 DEBUG:   * Flex 2.3 (flex)
14:05:29.072 DEBUG:   * Git 1.2 (scmgit)
14:05:29.072 DEBUG:   * SonarXML 1.4.3.1027 (xml)
14:05:29.072 DEBUG:   * SoftVis3D Sonar plugin 1.0 (softvis3d)
14:05:29.072 DEBUG:   * SonarPHP 2.11.0.2485 (php)
14:05:29.072 DEBUG:   * SonarTS 1.1.0.1079 (typescript)
14:05:29.072 DEBUG:   * SVN 1.5.0.715 (scmsvn)
14:05:29.072 DEBUG:   * SonarJS 3.3.0.5702 (javascript)
14:05:29.101 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
14:05:29.101 INFO: SonarQube server 6.7.0
14:05:29.101 INFO: Default locale: "de_DE", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
14:05:29.102 DEBUG: Work directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\a5fc21edc9db6866\.scannerwork
14:05:29.102 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
14:05:29.103 DEBUG: Execution execute
14:05:29.997 INFO: Process project properties
14:05:30.004 DEBUG: Process project properties (done) | time=6ms
14:05:30.050 INFO: Load project repositories
14:05:30.056 DEBUG: GET 404 http://teamcity:9000/batch/project.protobuf?key=MyProj | time=5ms
14:05:30.060 DEBUG: Project repository not available - continuing without it
14:05:30.064 INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=14ms
14:05:30.147 DEBUG: Available languages:
14:05:30.147 DEBUG:   * C# => "cs"
14:05:30.148 DEBUG:   * Python => "py"
14:05:30.148 DEBUG:   * Java => "java"
14:05:30.148 DEBUG:   * Flex => "flex"
14:05:30.148 DEBUG:   * XML => "xml"
14:05:30.148 DEBUG:   * PHP => "php"
14:05:30.150 DEBUG:   * TypeScript => "ts"
14:05:30.151 DEBUG:   * JavaScript => "js"
14:05:30.187 INFO: Load quality profiles
14:05:30.218 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?defaults=true | time=29ms
14:05:30.227 INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=40ms
14:05:30.237 INFO: Load active rules
14:05:30.439 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWAmibuEbXZi-9wv_dLM&p=1&ps=500 | time=202ms
14:05:30.988 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWANnNk3QgX7CJzKVpGk&p=1&ps=500 | time=427ms
14:05:31.094 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWANnNr-QgX7CJzKVpMK&p=1&ps=500 | time=46ms
14:05:31.129 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWANnNqpQgX7CJzKVpLL&p=1&ps=500 | time=21ms
14:05:31.254 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWANnNybQgX7CJzKVpR5&p=1&ps=500 | time=124ms
14:05:31.365 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWANnN1iQgX7CJzKVpT7&p=1&ps=500 | time=83ms
14:05:31.432 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWANnN8kQgX7CJzKVpWs&p=1&ps=500 | time=66ms
14:05:31.471 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWANnN_hQgX7CJzKVpXw&p=1&ps=500 | time=33ms
14:05:31.489 INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=1252ms
14:05:31.492 INFO: Load metrics repository
14:05:31.551 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/metrics/search?f=name,description,direction,qualitative,custom&ps=500&p=1 | time=58ms
14:05:31.610 INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=118ms
14:05:31.690 INFO: Project key: MyProj
14:05:31.691 DEBUG: Start recursive analysis of project modules
14:05:31.691 INFO: -------------  Scan MyProj
14:05:32.849 INFO: Load server rules
14:05:32.977 DEBUG: GET 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/rules/list.protobuf | time=124ms
14:05:33.017 INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=168ms
14:05:33.083 INFO: Base dir: C:\BuildAgent\work\a5fc21edc9db6866
14:05:33.083 INFO: Working dir: C:\BuildAgent\work\a5fc21edc9db6866\.scannerwork
14:05:33.095 INFO: Source paths: Sources
14:05:33.095 INFO: Test paths: Tests
14:05:33.096 INFO: Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: de_DE
14:05:33.213 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C# were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.cs : **/*.cs
14:05:33.214 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Python were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.py : **/*.py
14:05:33.214 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Java were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.java : **/*.java,**/*.jav
14:05:33.216 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Flex were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.flex : **/*.as
14:05:33.216 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language XML were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.xml : **/*.xml,**/*.xsd,**/*.xsl
14:05:33.216 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language PHP were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.php : **/*.php,**/*.php3,**/*.php4,**/*.php5,**/*.phtml,**/*.inc
14:05:33.218 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language TypeScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.ts : **/*.ts,**/*.tsx
14:05:33.218 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js,**/*.jsx,**/*.vue
14:05:33.223 DEBUG: Initializers : 
14:05:33.225 INFO: Index files
14:05:33.310 DEBUG: 'Sources\DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.MyTheme\AddResourcesToPackage.nuspec' indexed with language 'null'
...
...
...
14:05:35.027 DEBUG: 'Tests\TestFramework.Tests\TestAutomationTests.cs' indexed as test with language 'cs'
14:05:35.027 INFO: 1213 files indexed
14:05:35.029 INFO: Quality profile for cs: My way
14:05:35.029 INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
14:05:37.347 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
14:05:37.347 DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
14:05:37.386 DEBUG: 'C# Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
14:05:37.390 DEBUG: '[Deprecated] C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
14:05:37.393 DEBUG: 'C# Unit Test Results Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
14:05:37.395 DEBUG: 'Python Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.395 DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.404 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.404 DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.404 DEBUG: 'Flex' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.404 DEBUG: 'Flex Cobertura' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.408 DEBUG: 'PHP sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.408 DEBUG: 'TypeScript Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.408 DEBUG: 'TypeScript LCOV Coverage Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.408 DEBUG: 'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.462 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
14:05:37.462 DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
14:05:37.463 DEBUG: 'C# Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
14:05:37.463 DEBUG: '[Deprecated] C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
14:05:37.468 DEBUG: 'C# Unit Test Results Import' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
14:05:37.468 DEBUG: 'Python Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.471 DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.471 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.471 DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.471 DEBUG: 'Flex' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.475 DEBUG: 'Flex Cobertura' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.477 DEBUG: 'PHP sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.477 DEBUG: 'TypeScript Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.477 DEBUG: 'TypeScript LCOV Coverage Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.477 DEBUG: 'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
14:05:37.482 DEBUG: Sensors : C# Properties -> SonarJavaXmlFileSensor -> XML Sensor -> Analyzer for "php.ini" files -> C# -> Zero Coverage Sensor -> CPD Block Indexer
14:05:37.482 INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
14:05:37.482 WARN: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
14:05:37.484 WARN: No roslyn issues report not found for this project.
14:05:37.484 INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=2ms
14:05:37.484 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
14:05:37.564 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=80ms
14:05:37.564 INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
14:05:37.581 DEBUG: 'Sources/Core.Authority.UI/Connected Services/LicenseServiceWCF/LicenseService.xsd' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
14:05:37.585 DEBUG: Count lines in C:/BuildAgent/work/a5fc21edc9db6866/Sources/Core.Authority.UI/Connected Services/LicenseServiceWCF/LicenseService.xsd
14:05:37.782 DEBUG: 'Sources/Core.Authority.UI/Connected Services/LicenseServiceWCF/LicenseService1.xsd' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
14:05:37.782 DEBUG: Count lines in C:/BuildAgent/work/a5fc21edc9db6866/Sources/Core.Authority.UI/Connected Services/LicenseServiceWCF/LicenseService1.xsd
14:05:37.873 DEBUG: 'Sources/Core.Authority.UI/Connected Services/LicenseServiceWCF/LicenseService2.xsd' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
14:05:37.873 DEBUG: Count lines in C:/BuildAgent/work/a5fc21edc9db6866/Sources/Core.Authority.UI/Connected Services/LicenseServiceWCF/LicenseService2.xsd
14:05:37.937 INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=373ms
14:05:37.937 INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
14:05:37.969 INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=32ms
14:05:37.969 INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]
14:05:37.969 INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
14:05:37.969 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
14:05:38.187 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=218ms
14:05:38.187 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
14:05:38.187 DEBUG: org.sonar.scanner.cpd.deprecated.DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for cs
14:05:38.189 DEBUG: No CpdMapping for language cs
14:05:38.189 DEBUG: org.sonar.scanner.cpd.deprecated.DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for xml
14:05:38.189 DEBUG: No CpdMapping for language xml
14:05:38.189 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=2ms
14:05:38.193 DEBUG: 'Sources/DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.MyTheme/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
14:05:38.198 DEBUG: 'Sources/DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.MyTheme/Properties/Resources.Designer.cs' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
14:05:38.726 INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git
14:05:38.728 INFO: 467 files to be analyzed
14:05:38.779 DEBUG: readpipe [git, --version],C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
14:05:38.852 DEBUG: readpipe may return 'git version 2.10.1.windows.1'
14:05:38.852 DEBUG: remaining output:

14:05:38.857 DEBUG: readpipe [git, config, --system, --edit],C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
14:05:39.112 DEBUG: readpipe may return 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mingw32/etc/gitconfig'
14:05:39.112 DEBUG: remaining output:

14:09:26.696 DEBUG: Blame file Tests/TestFramework.Tests/TestAutomationTests.cs
...
...
...
14:09:26.995 INFO: 467/467 files analyzed
14:09:26.997 INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files
14:09:26.999 INFO: CPD calculation finished
14:09:34.501 INFO: Analysis report generated in 7353ms, dir size=1 MB
14:09:35.289 INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 787ms, zip size=658 KB
14:09:35.289 INFO: Analysis report generated in C:\BuildAgent\work\a5fc21edc9db6866\.scannerwork\scanner-report
14:09:35.292 DEBUG: Upload report
14:09:35.898 DEBUG: POST 200 http://teamcity:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=MyProj&projectName=MyProj | time=604ms
14:09:35.900 INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 608ms
Publishing artifacts
[Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\sonar_server.txt=>.teamcity/sonar/]
[Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]: C:/BuildAgent/temp/buildTmp/sonar_server.txt => .teamcity/sonar
[Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]: C:/BuildAgent/temp/buildTmp/sonar_server.txt => .teamcity/sonar
14:09:35.909 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://teamcity:9000/dashboard/index/MyProj
14:09:35.910 INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
14:09:35.910 INFO: More about the report processing at http://teamcity:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWAmzHhyF2rjhrlmqekU
14:09:35.910 DEBUG: Report metadata written to C:\BuildAgent\work\a5fc21edc9db6866\.scannerwork\report-task.txt
14:09:35.931 DEBUG: Post-jobs : 
14:09:35.935 INFO: Task total time: 4:06.820 s
14:09:35.935 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:09:35.935 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
14:09:35.935 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:09:35.935 INFO: Total time: 4:08.728s
14:09:36.013 INFO: Final Memory: 48M/115M
14:09:36.013 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:09:36.013 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
14:09:36.015 DEBUG: Execution stop
Process exited with code 0
```

The runner seems to process all files but doesn't analyze them.
MsBuild 14 and 15 are installed on the build agent.

I tried this with several versions of the sonar-csharp-plugin. Every version since 6.0 has this problem. (Older versions produce exceptions)

What can I do to repair the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the TeamCity plugin for SonarQube does not support .NET analysis (see comment from Domingos Silva):
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/SonarQube+Integration

Unfortunately this plugin was not developed by SonarSource and we cannot update it.

What you could try to do is to use generic script steps and execute the Begin and End commands of Scanner for MSBuild according our documentation:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's a bit strange since it has worked a few months ago. 
But your proposition is working. Thank you.

Comment: @Dresaan I guess before the TeamCity plugin used old version of Scanner for MSBuild that analyzed projects in MSBuild 12 compatibility mode. In this case the Begin/End steps were not needed, but the analysis was slow and much less precise. We removed that mode with Scanner for MSBuild 3.0 and SonarC# 6.0.